# Autofill text inputs with Selenium in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to automate a simple task with Python 3 using Selenium. Basically I have to fill 3 input texts (name, email and phone number) and then click on the confirmation button. I am able to do this with the function `sendKeys()` of Selenium after finding the element by XPath, but I want to do this by running a script in javascript to boost performance (basically I want the text inputs to be filled parallely rather than sequentially). This is my code:

```py
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('name01').text = '" + name + "';"
                      + "document.getElementById('phone01').value = '" + phoneNumber + "';"
                      + "document.getElementById('email01').value = '" + mail + "';"
                      + "document.getElementById('public-booking-confirm').click()")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="public-booking-confirm"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/button').click()
```

Strangely enough, the text gets filled in all the boxes but when the button gets pressed it says the text is missing from all of them (even if I press it manually). If I replace the text by hand then it works fine and with `sendKeys()` such error did not occur.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not what anyone wanna do. How much time does it take to enter `name, email and phone number` with selenium ? hardly few secs. I think selenium deserve that. and Why to have a third party library JS for this simple operation. anyway how much time could you save ?

Comment: You are right, this is not what anyone wanna do, this is what I wanna do xD. Selenium takes less than half a sec, but performance here is very important, hence my question.

Comment: How did you measure the performance ? Do you think that forcefully introduction of JS will make it to production ? The answer is big NO

Comment: It does, because rathern than filling the textboxes sequentially they all get filled at the same time. I have already tested this in other occasions and the boost is for granted, byt this time it just does not work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Sometimes browser does not handle fastest manupulations so I added `time.sleep(1)` between code blocks. I know this isn' t best practices but it works.

Another better way is `WebDriverWait` or as you said `SendKeys`

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element_timeout = 180
```

```
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, element_timeout).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "your_element_id")))
submit_button.click()
```

OR

```
submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, element_timeout).until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "your_element_id")))
submit_button.click()
```

**Edited Block**

Try this, it worked. Submit button may prevent because of some client validations.

```js
var name = "Full Name";
var phone = "323434234";
var email = "email@email.com";

document.getElementById("name01").value = name;
document.getElementById("phone01").value = phone;
document.getElementById("email01").value = email;

// Submit Button
document.querySelector("#public-booking-confirm > div > div.row.justify-content-center > div.row.justify-content-start.align-items-center.flex-column.w-100.px-3 > form > div.ml-0.mt-3.mt-md-0.floating-field.ng-star-inserted > button").click()
```

Comment: Unluckily this won't do the trick for me. Indeed the problem is not in timing as I still cannot go on with the click even if I do that "by hand". Only way is to replace the autofilled text with text written by me, as if the javascript code is filling the fields only "apparently"

Comment: Could you share the link me to try ?

Comment: Sure, [here it is](https://v2.waitwhile.com/book/milan/confirm)